# SAP GUI 770 - WSAECONNRESET Timeout every 5 minutes

Tags: sap-gui, sap-basis

I'm recently installed a new instance of SAP GUI 770 on my server, but for some reason im getting error 10054 (WSAECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer). Symptom: Timeout on SAP GUI every 5 minutes without do anything on client.
Things that i've already do:

- Increase/decrease of parameters -> rdisp/keepalive_timeout = 3600 and
  rdisp/keepalive = 20
- Put "true" on that -> enque/encni/set_so_keepalive
- Set autologout to 0 -> rdisp/gui_auto_logout = 0
- Disable Windows Firewall
- Open port 3299 on my permiter firewall (corporate)

Best regards,
Will